# How to draw something on Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

This is the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I know I can create a class

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
    }
}
```

And use it in activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);

}
```

But it must replace my original layout `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

If I use layout, I cannot draw something, if I draw something, I cannot use layout

How can I keep both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to do this, you can add the View to your XML layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <insert.your.real.package.DrawView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently, what you have will not support custom XML attributes. If you want to add XML Attributes, then, you need to add more constructors. A more detailed example is as given below

DrawView class

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        //you can also init your attributes here (if you have any)
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(20, 0, 0, 20, paint);
    }
}
```

For more information on using custom views be sure to read http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html. Hope this helps :)

Comment: It is not work. If I remove 3rd-4th constructor, and change `this(context, attrs, 0);` to `super(context, attrs, 0);`, then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a layout is an "addition" of view, a file (in your res/layout) that contain differents Views (like a TextView, EditText etc..) or ViewGroup (like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc...). You have to say to your activity wich layout you are going to use to represent your activity, you use setContentView(layout) to do it. So the thing you have to do is to put one of your file that are in your res/layout like that setContentView(R.layout.mylayout), mylayout here is the name of your file. Then in your mylayout.xml file you will have to add your custom view, here it's your DrawView. Exemple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<mypackagename.DrawView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So here what you have to do is add your custom View in your activity_main layout.

You could also put your custom view directly in the setContentView, but if you want it to contain child it should extends from ViewGroup.